# render visualforce page using ember.js mvc framework

Tags: ember.js, salesforce

1. How can we render visualforce page by using `ember.js` framework?
2. How can I bind server(`apex controller`) data with model so when
   template will load then data should be display on page? My server
   data is coming in json hierarchical form.
3. How can we assign more than one `json` variable to template.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to 1. check out https://github.com/mickle00/salesforce-emberjs. This repository contains a barebones ember.js app in a visualforce page.

When you build your Ember App in this visualforce page you can use javascript remoting to call your controller methods.

By the way, you'll probably get a better answer on the [salesforce stackexchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/)